# Batch files - encryption/decryption

Tags: batch-file, encryption

So In a folder on my computer there's files named after users. Ex: myth.uuid

In those .uuid files is text telling what a user's password is. Ex: 123567

I wanted a batch file to encrypt it to random mess but another batch file that can decrypt it back into plain text. Any ideas?
I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather obfuscation than encrytion :

```
certutil -encodehex myth.uuid myth.hex
certutil -decodehex myth.hex myth.uuid
```

or

```
certutil -encode myth.uuid myth.b64
certutil -decode myth.b64 myth.uuid
```

In both cases first line encodes the file and the second decodes it.First one to/from HEX the second Base64.You can use some combination for more obfuscated results.For encoding file to hex you can also check [file2hex.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/file2hex.bat) which will strip the data of the file and still you'll be able to use `certutil -decodehex`

Comment: How do I encode using a particular user account? If user A encodes a file in C:\Temp, user B should not be able to decode it.

Comment: @npocmaka using encodehex leaves the original text inside the .hex file along with the hex encoded text, so that won't work. using the b64 ecoding creates a zip file with a file named 0001.txt inside it and the content of that txt file is " -----END CERTIFICATE-----". But decoding it does bring back the original string so maybe this will work.

Comment: @Ghos3t - try [file2hex.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/file2hex.bat)  you'll have to pass the source file and the target file where the hex data will be saved.It will strip the original content.You'll still be able to decode the file with certutil.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways.  You could install [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and use `7za outfile.7z myth.uuid -pPassword` to encrypt.  You could use JScript with [xxtea.js](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/tea-block.html) and [base64.js](https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js) (or perhaps npocmaka's `certutil` method for base64 (en|de)coding.  You could install [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) to mount / umount an encrypted volume as needed.  You could install and use [GPG4Win](http://www.gpg4win.org/) as suggested by Maarten.  You could employ a PowerShell [Secure-String](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx) cmdlet.  You can use [`cipher.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490878.aspx) ([brief tutorial](http://ss64.com/nt/cipher.html)).  You can do probably dozens of other things to encrypt / decrypt from a command line.

Answer (score 2):

Use GPG encryption, the command line utility is also available pre-build for Windows. I would recommend public key encryption using a generated PGP key pair.